# Install crashlytics without fabric?

Tags: android, gradle, dex, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Fabric adds 1k methods of its own without the use of twitter kit, or mopub.

I just want to use crashlytics without retrieving it from fabric repos.

How can I accomplish such?

Can one point me towards crashlytics only maven/gradle repos?

Answer (score 1):

Use of kits are optional, you can decide what to use in your gradle dependencies section. If you want to use just Crashlytics you can simply remove the other dependencies:

**Before**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.mopub.sdk.android:mopub:3.2.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

**After**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Make sure to clean you project before updating.

Comment: Is the classpath, plugin, and repo still coming from fabric? How can I get that crashlytics aar from crashlytics sources? Fabric adds methods for no reason.